# Does anyone have the Codesys SysLibFile.lib file to share?

Tags: codesys

I am trying to save the values ​​of the PLC variables in a CSV file. I saw an example that uses the SysLibFile library, but I can't find it anywhere.
Does anyone have the SysLibFile.lib file to share?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This really isn't a question about code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Codesys 3, you can find SysFile library (I think thats the same):

1. Open library manager
2. Click add library,
3. Click advanced
4. Browse to System -> SysFile
5. Select the SysFile and hit OK

Then you can find the library under SysFile namespace.

If you are using Codesys 2, I can't help as I don't have it installed. Does the following link help?
http://www.exorint.net/webpage?ReadForm&wPageName=faq&t=ExorIntFAQTagsItem&c=JMobile&code=AGHO-A2CC3E